# Save UIWebView Access to Current Location

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, settings, geolocation, gps

A UIWebView in my app is loading up a site that is requesting access to the user's location.  In Safari, it stores this preference and does not ask it again, but in my app, it continues to ask every time.  Is there a way to store the user's preference on this so they are not asked every time they use the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this cannot be done under the current OS (iOS 4.0).

Comment: I was wondering the same thing - how did you come to this conclusion?